# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) And SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am getting error :

> 2023-07-21 06:57:32SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>
> 2023-07-21 06:57:32SMTP connect() failed.

I enabled `extension=php_openssl.dll`  and change `port=465` or `587` but it still doesn't work

php.ini

[image]

[image]

Class Send Mail

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include all relevant info (code, error, and configuration info) as text.

Comment: More on the reasons of ewokx request: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Most likely your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for what you can do about that.

Comment: Check outbound firewall rules. Check that your `getConstant` function returns what you think it does.  N.B. The mail config in your php.ini is irrelevant because you're doing SMTP directly to a 3rd party server, not using the local mail() config.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post code directly as text and format it with the formatting tools. To learn more about this, I would recommend you to read this: 
[No Screenshots of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)